# Did the Ancient One know about Xu Wenwu and the Ten Rings?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings, the-ancient-one

I would like to know if the Ancient One knew about Xu Wenwu and the Ten Rings since it was her job to protect the Earth from any magical/supernatural threats.

In the movie *Shang-Chi and The Legend of The Ten Rings (2021)*, Shang-Chi's father Xu Wenwu is

> 1000 years old

and the Ancient One had lived for 700 years within this same time period, so I would think that she would have been aware of him and the Ten Rings especially since he had used them a lot over the years.

Did the Ancient One know about Xu Wenwu and the Ten Rings?

Comment: "it was her job to protect the Earth from any magical/supernatural threats" — I'm not sure that's quite right. From *Doctor Strange*: "MORDO: The Sanctums protect the world, and we sorcerers protect the Sanctums. STRANGE: From what? MORDO: Other-dimensional beings that threaten our universe." I'm not sure the Ten Rings count as other-dimensional, so unless Wenwu attacked a Sanctum, his activities probably wouldn't have drawn the Ancient One's attention.

Comment: I don't see why this is closed.   The answer may be "there's no canon information on this", but the question is not about future works.   Otherwise we could call any question that currently has no canon answer "about future works".   Unless the question is specifically about a known upcoming work or one we have very good reason to believe will be upcoming, it's not a future works question.   This question should be open.

Answer (score 5):

### There is no in-universe confirmation of this. Likely, there never will be.

Seeing as *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* (2021) came after *Doctor Strange* (2016), and the Ancient One

> perishes towards the end of *Doctor Strange*,

it is rather unlikely that we will see confirmation of this. **As of January 2022, there is no ***MCU*** confirmation of the Ancient One knowing about Xu Wenwu.**

### There doesn't seem to be any reason for her to know

As Wong says in *Doctor Strange*:

> WONG: While heroes like the Avengers protect the world from physical dangers, **we sorcerers safeguard it against more mystical threats.**
>
> <sup>*Doctor Strange* (2016); emphasis added</sup>

Xu Wenwu's Rings were magic, sure, but he never attacked the Sanctums or Kamar-Taj (to our knowledge). He used them for worldly gain and to topple different regimes and world leaders, and if anything it made it more clear to threats like Dormammu and others that the Earth was protected. **The sorcerers kept the Earth safe from mystical threats, and while the Rings did have magic, they didn't mess with the mystical safety of the Earth.** Until,

### the Rings sent out a signal to some other force and Wong became involved.

*Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* takes place **after the Blip**, a five-year period during which 50% of Earth's population disappeared because of Thanos's snap. This included Steven Strange, who presumably became Sorcerer Supreme to replace the Ancient One after *Doctor Strange*. This caused Wong to become Sorcerer Supreme (and he retains his role post-Blip, as shown in *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021)) "on a technicality":

> STRANGE: He got it on a technicality because I blipped for five years.
>  <sup>*Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021)</sup>

At the *end* of *Shang-Chi*, Wong takes Katy and Shang-Chi to what is presumably the Sanctum in New York, where he explains that the Rings are emitting a signal of some sort that the sorcerers were able to detect and that possibly is being sent to some otherworldly being or race, but that this started **only ***after*** Shang-Chi used the Rings for the first time.**

> WONG: The first time you used the rings, **we felt it in Kamar-Taj.**
>
> <sup>*Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* (2021); emphasis added</sup>

This shows that the sorcerers (and more specifically, Wong) are attentive to matters regarding the Rings after Shang-Chi is in possession of them because a possible mystic threat is involved. However, until the point that Shang-Chi used the Rings for the first time, a such signal had not been sent by the Rings.

Comment: Shang-Chi is not set during the Blip. It is post blip according to multiple official sources...and Bruce's arm is in a sling which is post-Endgame

Comment: Oh, okay... I thought it was during the blip. I'm gonna edit my answer, thanks! Somehow I had it wrong in my head